# i get the error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type string to UnityEngine.UI.Text while making a pong scoreboard

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, pong

I am making pong and im currently trying to make the scoreboard, it gives me the error `CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type string to UnityEngine.UI.Text`

I am new to code and i have not tried anything except messing around with the variables

```
public static Text ScoreBoard;
public static int LeftScore = 0;
public static int RightScore = 0;


GameManager.ScoreBoard = GameManager.RightScore.ToString() + "-" + 
GameManager.LeftScore.ToString();


public static Text ScoreBoard;
public static int LeftScore = 0;
public static int RightScore = 0;


GameManager.ScoreBoard = GameManager.RightScore.ToString() + "-" +
```

It was printing the score to the console but I cant get it to change in the ui

I expect it to print like `"00 - 00"`

Comment: scoreboard is a text component, not the property text.. so you want scoreboard.text ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't convert string to ui text in unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48995668/cant-convert-string-to-ui-text-in-unity)

Answer (score 0):

A System.String is a collection of characters that represents text.

A UnityEngine.UI.Text is a graphical representation of a String on a UI Canvas to be displayed on-screen.

Right now, you're trying to tell Unity to use just the String (which does nothing on it's own) instead of the Text object you already have set up.

What you want to do instead is set the Text's value to the value of the String so it displays what's stored in the String.  To do so, you'll want to assign it to the Text's 'text' property instead of assigning it to the Text variable itself, like so:

```
GameManager.ScoreBoard.text = GameManager.RightScore.ToString() + "-" + GameManager.LeftScore.ToString();
```